# C#: Running a transaction on SQL Server 2008 via ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactions

Using the following method I am able to run a transaction against an Oracle database using ADO.NET. When I try the same code on an SQL Server database I get the error shown. What is the cause of this and how can it be fixed?

**The error:**

> *ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the
>   connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. 
>   The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.*

**The Code:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A method to run transactional SQL on a database. Does not return a record set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="transactions">A list of commands</param>
    /// <returns>A boolean indicator of success</returns>
    public bool ExecuteTransactionNonQuery(List<string> transactions)
    {
        if (transactions == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("transactions");
        }

        PrepareConnection();

        DbTransaction dbTransaction = DBFactoryDatabaseConnection.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            foreach (var transaction in transactions)
            {

                DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.CommandText = transaction;
                DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            dbTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            dbTransaction.Rollback();
            try
            {
                Close();
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: Transaction execute failed on the database. " + ex.Message + ". Following that the application failed to close the connection. " + f.Message + ". ExecuteTransactionNonQuery().");
            }
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dbTransaction.Dispose();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Set the Command.Transaction property to the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the **transaction** to the **command**.

```cs
DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.Transaction = dbTransaction;
```

Comment: Can you show where that line needs to go in my code? I assume after the command text is assigned? Does this have to be done every time you have done an execute?

Comment: It needs to go before `DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. If the connection is associated with a transaction, then yes it needs assigned every time.